# Replace long/lat on Google maps via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this map script from Google Maps implemented on my site. What I'd like to do is I'd like to replace the latitude and longitude numbers (`lat` & `lng`) with numbers I've fetched from an API via AJAX.

The variables containing the longitude numbers and latitude numbers are returned like: `data.mondayLat` & `data.mondayLong` via the successfunction of AJAX. I've tried just replacing the default map setting `00.0000000` with `data.mondayLat`, but that isn't working. How do I make those variables continuously replace the default numbers in the map function, and make the map update each time I fetch data via AJAX?

```
<script>
function initMap() {
  /* The following variable data I want to replace with the AJAX responde numbers */
  var myLatLng = {lat: 00.0000000, lng: 00.0000000};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Today we are here'
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;float:lefT;margin-left:20px;border:3px solid;"></div>
```

Comment: You can simply re-center the map with your new coordinates. GMaps has a ton of examples in their docs.

Comment: @Marcus Sure but the problem is that I have the coords I want saved in two variables (via ajax), but I can't figure out how to make them work inside that map function

Comment: Your AJAX request is asynchronous.  Call the initMap routine in the AJAX success function once you have the results (data.mondayLat and data.mondayLong exist).

Comment: Post your ajax call then. Your code above does nothing in terms of grabbing, and plotting, new coords.

Comment: @geocodezip I'm like retarded or something today. Thank you. Mind posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX request is asynchronous. Call the `initMap` routine in the AJAX success function once you have the results (`data.mondayLat` and `data.mondayLong` exist).